# keras.utils.Sequence does not work as I want when I use predict_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My model expects to receive two input arrays when making a predict. (value, label)

```
    train_model = models.Model(inputs=[x, y], outputs=[out_seg, shared_decoder(masked_by_y, conv_cap_2_1, x )]) # [x:image,y: mask] // [out_seg:length, reconstruction output]
```

So I made the following class using Sequence.

```
class No_decoder_sequence(keras.utils.Sequence):
 def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
    self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
    self.batch_size = batch_size

 def __len__(self):
    return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

 def __getitem__(self, idx):
    batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_x = np.expand_dims(batch_x ,-1)
    batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

    return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)
```

However, an error occurs when I attempt to use the class to predict as follows:

```
 no_decoder_generator_1 = No_decoder_sequence(X_val_1, y_val_1, batch_size=1)
 y_predict_1, x_predict_1 = model.predict_generator(generator=no_decoder_generator_1, steps=len(X_val_1))
 y_predict_1 = np.asarray(y_predict_1)
 x_predict_1 = np.asarray(x_predict_1)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays: [array([[[[ 0.9287956 ],.

Why is my `No_decoder_sequence` returning only one array value?

[image]

And how do I check the values sequence class returns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclass of keras.utils.Sequence does not get the value I want when I use predict\_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908056/subclass-of-keras-utils-sequence-does-not-get-the-value-i-want-when-i-use-predic)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I could not get the reply to the article and uploaded it again. If it is a problem, I will delete the previous article. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is a problem, you should not post questions more than once, this isn't a forum.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I got it. I deleted previous thing. Thank you! I didn't know that